# Avoid delete animation when replacing win-flip-view items in a WinJS WP app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, animation, winjs, flipview

I'm writing a WinJS app for Windows Phone 8.1 using AngularJS and angular-winjs adapter and have a FlipFiew control in it using the win-flip-view directive.

The model behind the flipview lives in the controller as an array of objects in $scope.items. The content of the array can get updated externally so, when that happens, I get notified with the new array and then I replace $scope.items with the new array inside a $apply so Angular processes it properly.

Sometimes, the only change is in the content of the last item, so there are no changes to the length of the array neither to the rest of the items. Then, when the $scope.items changes, I see the last item is removed with a fade-out-like animation and a new item is created in its place, which is not a good experience if it happens the user is having that item in the screen.

Ionic Framework has an option to control wherer or not removing an item from a list triggers the fade-out animation (item-remove-animate) but in WinJS/angular-winjs it looks like the animation is on by default.

How can I disable that animation on remove-and-insert so the user just sees the content of the item changing instead of the item being removed and a new item created a second later?